# Displaying number of days associated with a picklist value of a picklist field configured on Salespath on Opportunity

Tags: lightning-experience, salespath

we use standard Stage field in salespath,  when you hover over the path stage you see how long the opportunity has been in this stage.

My problem is I do not see this function for SalesPath path configured with custom picklist field. When I hover over the path for this, I just get the stage name. I am using different path for different record type of an Opportunity.

Is there anything I am missing? Or, this is currently a limitation in Lightning?

Comment: The standard Stage Name field has always been tracked, so it makes that they'd include this as a standard feature for this field. As far as I can tell, there is no way to display this sort of data even if you enable field history tracking for the field.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the information. So i assume currently this is a kind of limitation in Lightning.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is not a feature that exists right now. If you want to call it a limitation, fine, but it's really just not a feature.